# Is there a Bilal Hadith

Tags: hadith

Is there a hadith/Ahadith reported by Bilal(R.A) because he was also a  close companio of the prophet and am yet to see a hadith narration reported in his name,he must also have heared or seen something.

Comment: Which Bilal? Bilal Alvozé, Bilal Al Haares, Bilal An Alrebaa... ?

Answer (score 3):

Salam Alaykom,

- Found in Sahih Muslim: Purification (Kitab Al-Taharah) , Hadith #535

  Narrated by Bilal:
  that the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) wiped over the socks and turban, and         in the hadith transmitted by 'Isa b. Yaunus the words are:" Bilal narrated it to me."
- Sunan of Abu-Dawood, Hadith #534

  Narrated by Bilal:
  The Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) said to Bilal: Do not call adhan until the dawn  appears clearly to you in this way, stretching his hand in latitude.
- Sunan of Abu-Dawood, Hadith #1252

  Narrated by Bilal:
  Ziyadah al-Kindi reported on the authority of Bilal that he (Bilal) came to the Apostle   of Allah (peace be upon him) to inform him about the dawn prayer. Aisha kept Bilal engaged in a matter which she asked him till the day was bright and it became fairly light. Bilal then stood up and called him to prayer and called him repeatedly. The Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) did not yet come out. When he came out, he led the people in prayer and he (Bilal) informed him that Aisha had kept him engaged in a matter which she asked him till it became fairly light; hence he became late in reaching him (in time). He (Bilal) said: Apostle of Allah, the dawn became fairly bright. He said: If the dawn became brighter than it is now, I would pray them (the two rak'ahs of the sunnah prayer), offer them well and in a more beautiful manner.
- Al-Tirmidhi Hadith, Hadith #646

  Narrated by Bilal:
  Allah's Messenger (peace be upon him) said to me: Don't pronounce these words, `Prayer is better than sleep ' in the call for prayer, but for the dawn prayer only.
  Transmitted by Tirmidhi, Ibn Majah.

On another spot I've found that Bilal (May Allah have mery on his soul) narrated 44 hadith, but I couldn't find any of them, besides the ones I've listed. Your question indeed is a very interesting one, I have never thought about it, but now I'll try to find more about hadith narrated by Bilal, insha Allah.

Salam Alaykom Wa Rahmetullahi Wa Berekatuhu.